# Define a Protocol for __getitem__ that works with generic types

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pyright

Im trying to define a Protocol for `__getitem__` to accept anything (including generic types) that implements the method.

```py
from typing import Protocol
class AnySeq(Protocol):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        ...

def f(x: AnySeq):...

f([1,2,4]) # error
```

Unfortunately, the type checker shouts at me because

> Argument of type "list[int]" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "AnySeq" in function "f".
>
> "list[int]" is incompatible with protocol "AnySeq"
>
> "`__getitem__`" is an incompatible type
>
> No overloaded function matches type "(key: Unknown) -> None"

Try as i might, i cant make it work, generic `Protocol[T]` (returning `T` from `__getitem__`) doesnt help, explicit `Any` doesnt help either.

I suspect i need to match the signature exactly, but that defeats the purpose of a protocol: i need to support everything from `list`s to `polars.Series` to `nupmy.ndarray`s and i dont mind the type checker not being able to see the return type of the `__getitem__`, it is type checked a bit earlier. To give a bit of context, the semi-working (oversimplified) version of the code is the following (it does what i want, it just requires `Sequence` to define `count` which nobody ever implements, rendering `Sequence` useless):

```
def calculate_distances(
    things: Sequence[T],
    distance: Callable[[T, T], np.float64],
) -> np.ndarray[np.floating[Any], Any]:
    dists = np.empty((len(things), len(things)), dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(len(things)):
        for j in range(len(things)):
            if i != j:
                dists[i, j] = distance(things[i], things[j])
    return dists
```

Of course, the example is oversimplified, imagine i actually need the `things` parameter to have `__getitem__` and cant just change the loop a bit.

Edit for clarity: I need to support **generic** classes that are already written by a third party and thus **cant subclass** my classes.

Comment: Whoever closed this - none of the answers in the linked Q/A solves this problem. OP - you need to define your signature to be compatible with [`list.__getitem__`'s signature](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/9d90eeb29646f88937bcee38e4dd954a6a769ed2/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L999-L1002). In your case, the major problem is that, in your current signature, the `key` parameter is not positional-only, unlike `list.__getitem__`. Try `def __getitem__(self, key: Any, /) -> Any`.

Comment: Not sure the linked duplicate is helpful.  I was in the middle of posting an answer which, in short, requires the use of an explicit covariant type variable `T` in making `AnySeq` generic: `T = TypeVar('T', covariant=True); class AnySeq(Protocol[T]): def __getitem__(self, key: SupportsIndex) -> T: ...`.